# Почему не удается запустить терминал нажатием кнопки в приложении?

Tags: python, pyqt5

При нажатии на кнопку "выполнить" должен открываться терминал и выполнять команду ls -l. Но не работает кнопка. Вот основной код приложения main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import os, subprocess

class Example(QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    qbtn = QPushButton('Выполнить', self)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
    qbtn.move(50, 50)
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')
    self.show()

  def btnClicked():
    subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])

  if __name__ == '__main__':

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Не`def btnClicked():`, а `def btnClicked(self):`
2. При запуске `subprocess.run` у вас наверняка будет исключение `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:`, которое нужно ловить, иначе приложение упадет. В примере ниже покажу как это делать
3. Не `subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])`, а `subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)`

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox
import subprocess


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')

        button_run = QPushButton('Выполнить')
        button_run.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button_run)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def btnClicked(self):
        subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = Example()
    mw.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPD.**

Добавил пример [открытия окна консоли](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788433/5909792) с командой.

```
subprocess.run(["start", "cmd.exe", "@cmd", "/k", "ipconfig"], shell=True)
```

Через `os.system`:

```
import os
...
    def btnClicked(self):
        os.system("start cmd.exe @cmd /k ipconfig")
```

---

**PS.**

Можете посмотреть [тут пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2ba260415891dd4fcb1a11235c9dffad3e2d5267/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/run_cmd_in_new_window.py#L43) по вызову терминала через клик

Comment: Попробовал полностью ваш вариант, не работает. Терминал не вызывается. Скажите, где можно указать путь к терминалу?

Comment: @ArturHan, у меня вызывается, пишет в консоль скрипта. Если вы хотели чтобы появлялось окно с консолью (терминалом), то это другое

Comment: Да мне нужно окно терминала

Comment: Какая ОС? Windows?

Comment: Xubuntu 18.04 lts

Comment: @ArturHan, у меня нет возможности проверить на линуксе, поэтому попробуйте сами, например `subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'ls', '-l'], shell=True)`

Comment: 'gnome-terminal' это название программы? А как приложение само найдет путь к исполняемому файлу?

Comment: @ArturHan, да, название. У вас тот код не работает? Думаю, к этому терминалу должен быть `alias`, если нет, придется полный путь указывать и возможно без `shell=True`

Comment: А где найти алиас терминала?

Comment: @ArturHan, к сожалению, сам я проверить не могу, поэтому только гуглением: https://askubuntu.com/questions/401009/command-to-open-new-terminal-window-from-the-current-terminal https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140101/shortcut-to-open-xfce4-terminal-and-run-history-command-on-xubuntu-16-04-6 https://askubuntu.com/questions/217079/how-to-open-terminal-on-xubuntu